# SSL Certificate with Nginx and Apache

Tags: 14.04, apache2, nginx, webserver, ssl

I have an Ubuntu 20.04 server running with Apache and Nginx. I want to add an SSL certificate using Certbot but I don't know how to proceed.

My project consists of a django api and a Vue js frontend.
Nginx is responsible for the API and apache acts as a reverse proxy.

My Apache 000-default.conf file

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
        DocumentRoot /var/www/html

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName ***.***.** <- My IP
    ProxyPass / http://127.0.0.1:8000/
    ProxyPassReverse / http://127.0.0.1:8000/
</VirtualHost>
```

My Nginx config

```
upstream django {
    server unix:///home/backend/mysite.sock;
}

server {
    listen      8000;
    server_name mysite.com;
    charset     utf-8;

    client_max_body_size 75M;

    location /media  {
        alias /home/backend/media;
    }

    location /static {
        alias /home/backend/static;
    }

    location / {
        uwsgi_pass  django;
        include     /home/backend/uwsgi_params;
    }
}
```

Thank you if someone informs me how can I install an ssl certificate with Certbot using this configuration

Comment: And you tried the [documented certbot procedure](https://certbot.eff.org/lets-encrypt/ubuntufocal-apache), and it didn't work for you? How did it fail?

Answer (score 0):

Follow below steps to configure SSL with certbot.

1. Install certbot

   ```
   sudo apt install python-certbot-apache
   ```
2. Make sure DNS records pointing to your server and then generate certificate

   ```
   sudo certbot --apache -d domain.com -d www.domain.com
   ```
3. If sucessfull it will produce below output and prompt for http to https redirection

> Please choose whether or not to redirect HTTP traffic to HTTPS,
> removing HTTP access.
> ------------------------------------------------------------------------------- 1: No redirect - Make no further changes to the webserver
> configuration. 2: Redirect - Make all requests redirect to secure
> HTTPS access. Choose this for new sites, or if you're confident your
> site works on HTTPS. You can undo this change by editing your web
> server's configuration.
> ------------------------------------------------------------------------------- Select the appropriate number [1-2] then [enter] (press 'c' to
> cancel):

4. Select appropriate number as per your requirement. Once finished it will load certficate in apache automatically.